# How to run a method immediately after starting up the program?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using C# WPF, but I can't figure out how to start a method after I start the .exe file. I have made a console application and I do not want to see any forms/windows.

I got rid of the whole `MainWindow()` method, and I also added the method I want to call in my `Main()` method. I deleted the `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` line from the App.xaml and I expected the software to run the `Main()` method on start up, but instead it keeps calling the `MainWindow()` method from my `MainWindow.cs` class. I know that, because when I put back my `MainWindow()` method it executed everything inside that method.

The first thing that I tried was putting my method calling in the `MainWindow()` method, but it keeps looping and I do not want it to. I guess a work around for that would be endless `Thread.Sleep()`, but that seems like a really stupid thing to do.

Here is what my `Main()` method looks like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Application Entry Point.
    /// </summary>
    [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public static void Main() {
          System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("it's working"); //shows this message it this method is called
    }
```

Here is the whole `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="PHAutoProcess.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: If you really created an Console-Application you wouldn't have any XAML... Probably you did not create an Console-App, but an WPF Application. Try looking for the Console-App in VS.

Comment: @Gope, yeah you are right. I used `Properties => Output type and I changed that to "Console application"`. I thought that was enough.

Comment: Your understanding of entry points and WPF is wrong. The `MainWindow()` method is actually a constructor of the `MainWindow` class - removing it only means you're not going to run the proper constructor logic, but the constructor is still there. It doesn't help you at all. Figure out if you want a GUI application or not - if yes, use the proper events in WPF. If not, use a console application (the entry point is specified in project settings).

Comment: Changing the output type only means you now *also* have a console, apart from the main GUI application. Either create a new project with the Console application template, or remove the WPF stuff - `App.xaml` is also part of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good you found it. You can mark this comment as answer then... :)

If you really created an Console-Application you wouldn't have any XAML... Probably you did not create an Console-App, but an WPF Application. Try looking for the Console-App in VS